# Netlogo: Iterating Over Lists

Tags: list, netlogo

I would like to use this part of code in NetLogo:

```
foreach [2 4 6]
  [ crt ?
    show "created " + ? + " turtles" ]
```

It comes from documentation – [Iterating over lists](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/2.0/docs/programming.html#lists).
But when I run code, this error message displays:

> expected this input to be a number, but got a string instead

If I leave + from show command, then there is no error, but therefore I cannot write iteration number.
Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use a newer version of NetLogo (this is the help for Netlogo 2.x)
Check the new example here :
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/programming.html#lists

And the associated code :

```
  foreach [2 4 6]
  [
    crt ?
    show (word "created " ? " turtles")
  ]
```